# The "disable" tag is meta and can be removed

Tags: discussion, tags

[disable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disable) is meta, it can probably be removed.

Comment: This tag is [active on the *main* site](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disable). When will this tag be disable? *(if you'll pardon the pun)*

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, this should be removed. Nobody can be an expert in the general practice of turning stuff off. There's no reason anyone would subscribe to this tag, and it tells us nothing about the nature of the questions being asked.

- Even together with a question's other tags, it tells us nothing. Suppose a question is tagged [internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet) and [disable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disable). Does that mean the OP wants to disable their Internet connection? That the *problem* is that it's disabled? That they want to disable pop-ups while browsing the web?

Also, second language speakers could become confused between *disable* and *disability* (in the sense of *accessibility*).